# What's the difference between Title and Product in visual studio projects?

Tags: vb.net

Under Assembly Information in my projects I see Title and Product. Aren't they the same thing?

MSDN says the title is "Friendly name for the assembly" and the product is a the name of the product, but that doesn't help at all.

Comment: Multiple projects could be part of the same product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on a .dll or .exe, select Properties and go to the Details tab.  Title is what is displayed as the File Description, and Product is displayed as the Product name.  So for example, the title of an assembly could be, "DLL that contains database functions," and the Product Name would be the name of the product that the assembly belongs to, such as "Contoso Point of Sale."

Comment: So for a project you really don't need a title, just a product name whereas an assembly should have just a title and doesn't really need the product name.

Comment: I would say that is a fair approach, but technically neither of them is really needed, so it depends on your needs.  If the binaries are going to be installed on numerous customers' machines, then there is some value in having some data in those fields.  If it is code that will never run on anyone's machine but yours, then there's not much need for those fields to have anything.